# Wrong URL to CSS and JS after change domain

Tags: migration, domain

I made a clone of my wordpress website and I published it on other domain. I used [wp-migrate-db](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) plugin to change domain in database and it looks almost perfect, but.. I have a problem with CSS and JS files URLs problem. Still have old domain. I checked database - looks good. I do not know how this URL is generated?

```html
<head>
  <!--...-->
  <link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//old-domain.com' />
  <!--...-->
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='twentytwenty-style-css'  href='http://old-domain.com/assets/themes/twentytwenty/style.css' media='all' />
  <!--...-->
  <script src='http://old-domain.com/assets/themes/twentytwenty/assets/js/index.js' id='twentytwenty-js-js' async></script>
  <!--...-->
```

About what I forgot?

Comment: These should be based on the URLs in _Settings > General_. Are they what you expect?

Comment: after converted database by wp-migrate-db I do not need it

Comment: That doesn't answer my question?